# mysql and php updates only with zero

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a problem with updating a table. The update takes place in a class.

```
$sql= $pdo->prepare("insert into table1 (iduser)  VALUES (:i)");
$i=$this->idu;
$sql->bindParam(":i",$i);
$sql->execute();
```

the update takes place, but regardless of the parameter I send, the iduser column is always 0 (zero).
I don't know where the problem may be.
Can you help me please ?

Comment: Why are you creating an intermediate variable `$i` which serves no practical purpose?

Comment: It sounds like maybe $this->idu is not what you think it is? If that is true then the problem is outside the code that you posted. Try to use echo or a debugger and see what it really contains at the time you call bindParam.

Comment: Exactly as RobP saies. Or simply do a die($this->idu); before the bindParam method.

Comment: I am sorry for disappointing you, but this query updates nothing.

Comment: I found the error: $sql->bindParam(":i",$i); doesn't work, but $sql->bindParam(":i",$this->idu); worked. Do you know why ?

Comment: with this code it works. but with other code you may run but didn't post here it may bind a zero